# How do I make a background video autoplay on mobile Safari on iOS 9.3.5?

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, mobile-safari, autoplay

Edit: Figured it out - used this library: https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video.

I know this question has been asked, and is generally attributed to hooking into *some* kind of user interaction, but this is literally just loading the [page](http://www.airforce.com), video starts playing in background. Any ideas on how they're achieving video autoplay on mobile Safari on iOS 9.3.5?

Comment: Very bad asked question. You added bad link. Did you mean opening of the website, with background video, using mobile safari? Please edit.

Comment: The link works for me, dunno why it's being problematic for you. Yes, when you open the site in mobile safari on iPhone iOS 9.3.5, the the first section fills the viewport and has a background video that starts playing as soon as the page has loaded.

Comment: No, I'm asking how this site, the United States Air Force (you can just Google US Air Force if the link isn't working; it's their main site) works around the iOS limitation on autoplaying videos without explicit user interaction: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: The core issue is I also would like to autoplay a background video on my site in much the same fashion, but I'm not sure what methodology they are using to circumvent this limitation imposed by iOS.

Comment: Probably that video, as it autoplays in the browser, https://www.airforce.com/version/1471952108/data/video/hero/home_header_video.mp4 does the trick and hacks something. I would try to imitate the AF's website VIDEO tag syntax as much as it's possible and watch eventual problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122232/discussion-between-pedrouan-and-coupdecoop).